# Roxygen2: @return mismatched braces or quotes

Tags: r, return-value, documentation-generation, roxygen2

I am using rowxygen2 (version 7.1.1) and cannot get my function return list value to parse properly. Imput:

```
#' @return A list with the following fields: 
#' \describe{
#' \item{ID}{The speaker / speaker + session identifier of the output}
#' \item{CPPS}{Smoothed Cepstral Peak Prominence value}
#' \item{HNR}{An Harmonic-to-noise estimate}
#' \item{Shim_local}{A (local) Shimmer measurement (in %)}
#' \item{Shim_local_DB}{A (local) Shimmer measurement, in decibels}
#' \item{LTAS_Slope}{The slope of the Long Time Average Spectrum (in dB)}
#' \item{LTAS_Tilt}{The Long Time Average Spectrum tilt (in dB)}
#' \item{AVQI}{Acoustic Voice Quality Index summarizing the measures above}
#' }
```

gives the warning "@return mismatched braces or quotes" when running it through roxygen2, and I get nothing in the "\value" field in the Rd file.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of the "%":

```
#' \item{Shim_local}{A (local) Shimmer measurement (in %)}
```

to replace with

```
#' \item{Shim_local}{A (local) Shimmer measurement (in \%)}
```

Otherwise, the characters following the "%" are discarded.